# Asynchronous programming (TPL)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm wondering, how can I prove that `DownloadStringTaskAsync` method was fired in the same thread or not as Main method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        Task<string> resultFromWebClient = w.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=batman");
        Console.WriteLine($"result = {resultFromWebClient.Result}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What thread a task runs on is up to the TaskScheduler to decide (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx).

Thus, in most cases, this is undefined. It mostly depends on which threads are available from a thread pool. E.g. if there are none avaliable, the task will have to wait to be assigned a thread.

However, in your case it most certainly will not run on the same thread because your Main() method never releases it's thread to the thread pool, because it does not await anything.

To figure out which thread your async method call occurs on you could write your code:

```
Task<string> resultFromWebClient = w.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=batman");
```

into it's equivalent form:

```
Task<string> resultFromWebClient = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var myCurrentThreadIs = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;
    return await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=batman").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

DownloadStringTaskAsync() can run on multiple threads however, because it's internal code may await something and release it's thread to the thread pool, and be assigned a different thread when resuming. The code above will determine which thread it is first assigned. You may use ConfigureAwait(true) to make it synchronize back onto it's previous context, but that is not a guarantee to synchronize it back onto the initial thread. That is up to the particular SynchronizationContext.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I prove that DownloadStringTaskAsync method was fired in the same thread or not as Main method.

Well, you could enable network tracing and examine the thread id in the ETW logs.

Or, you could just make your own `async` method and test that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  WebClient w = new WebClient();
  Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
  Task<string> resultFromWebClient = GetAsync(w);
  Console.WriteLine($"result = {resultFromWebClient.Result}");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task<string> GetAsync(WebClient w)
{
  Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
  return await w.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=batman");
}
```